# Google sheets - programmatically change cell background

Tags: google-sheets, colors, background, conditional-formatting

I know that I can use conditional formatting to set a cell background based on the content of another cell.  But, is there a way to **directly** set a cell background via another cell's content, eg using an rgb value?

Something like this:

```
Cell 1A = "255,0,0"
Cell 2A background is red.
Change Cell 1A to "0,255,0"
Cell 2A background changes to green.
```

?

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set the cell background value using `setBackground`:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange("B1");
  cell2.setBackground(cell);
}
```

This is how the value was set in the Sheet:

[image]

If you want to use `setBackgroundRGB` then you can use this code instead:

```
function ondEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(cell)

  let cellinput = cell.split(',')
  
  
  const cellinput2 = cellinput.map((ele)=> (Number(ele)))
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange("B2");

  cell2.setBackgroundRGB(...cellinput2);
}
```

And this will be the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - how can I set that up so that I can make a custom function called setBackgroundFrom(cell) and then in B2 i can write "=setBackgroundFrom(A1)" (and then transpose that formula down a column by click and drag for example)? Sorry for not making it clear that I didn't want it to be hard coded to use A1 and B1.

Comment: I'm afraid that custom formulas can't perform such actions as documented in the [App Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) This is due to the method `setBackgroundRGB` part of the set methods available.